# When to use 'a' and when to use 'para'?

Tags: preposiciones

Es correcto decir 'Voy a Chicago' y 'Voy para Chicago'  (I'm going to Chicago)?

If so , how and when 'a' and 'para' are different?

Answer (score 7):

Usado con verbos de movimiento como «**ir**» y con lugares hay una diferencia:

> Voy **a** Chicago.

Tienes asuntos que hacer en Chicago.  Chicago es el destino de un viaje que planeas hacer o estás haciendo.

> Voy **para** Chicago.

Estás en camino, en movimiento o a punto de partir.  El destino (final o inmediato) del itinerario es Chicago, pero Chicago es más un referente que un propósito.

Estos sentidos son algo intercambiables y la preposición afecta más el sentido del verbo, en este caso «**ir**» entre un viajar como un propósito («ir a Chicago») o como un proceso («ir para Chicago»).

---

Using with movement verbs such as *«**ir**»* and with places there is a difference:

> *Voy **a** Chicago*

You have business in Chicago. Chicago is the destination of a trip you are planning to do or you are doing.

> *Voy **para** Chicago*

You are in motion or next to depart.  The (final or intermediate) destination is Chicago, but Chicago is rather a geographical reference than a purpose.

These senses might be a little exchangeable and the preposition rathers affect the verb, in this case *«**ir**»* from traveling as a purpose (*«ir a Chicago»*) and as a process (*«ir para Chicago»*).

Comment: Había un chiste de un gallego que no sabía decir si iba a Lugo o para Lugo...

Answer (score 1):

'a' is mostly used for a destination:

"Voy a Chicago" (destination)

"Voy a la entrega de premios" (the destination of the trip is the award dining itself)

'para' is mostly used for a reason:

"Voy a Chicago para la entrega de premios" (the destination of the trip is Chicago, as a whole, you may spend some days there, but the reason you are going to Chicago is the award dining)

Comment: Clearly you meant "destination" (destino de un viaje), not destiny (destino en la vida, lo que la fortuna te tiene reservado). :)

Comment: this answer does not address the use of "para" mentioned in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, you could use "a" if you can substitute with "towards" in the english version; and you could use "para" if you can substitute with "to" or "for". This is very rough, but could help you in case of doubt.

Answer (score -1):

**a** y **para** son preposiciones que pueden ser utilizadas de forma indistinta, cuando te refieres a un punto al que te dirijas como en tus ejemplos

- *Voy a Chicago*
- *Voy para Chicago*

**a** and **para** are prepositions that can be used without changing the meaning of your phrase, when you're talking about somewhere you are giong to, like in your samples

- *Voy a Chicago*
- *Voy para Chicago*